# google-compute-engine: Attempting to ssh into instance - getting Permission Denied

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I am using the `gcutil` to attempt to SSH into my new Google Cloud instance.  When it went through the set up, it asked me to enter a passphrase.  Now when I attempt to access the instance, it requests the passphrase, I enter it, and I get Permission Denied.

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> INFO: Running command line:
>
> ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/admin/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 root@173.255.119.141 --
>
> Warning: Permanently added '173.255.119.141' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: Do you have the correct certificate file around? It's definitively not loggin in with passphrase, but rather with publickey (`publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic`)

Comment: Hmmm... I went through the install process on this - when they asked me for the passphrase and I entered it twice - wouldn't it also create the certificate file?  How do I reset to go back through that process? or ensure a cert file is present?

Answer (score 1):

The passphrase you entered when you set it up initially should be the one for `/Users/admin/.ssh/google_compute_engine`. From the output you've got here, I'd suggest you try with the username of "admin" instead of "root". If that fails, then open the console webpage and make sure you've got the ssh-key entered into the metadata for this VM.

Answer (score 0):

We have created a startup script to self-manage and troubleshoot ssh connectivity issues https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-ssh-diagnostic-sh/